# Python callable attribute assign raise NotImplementedError

Tags: python, exception

In an abstract class, I want to assign a `NotImplemented` exception to a callback object.

```
self._button_clicked: Callable[[None], None] = raise NotImplementedError()
```

Unfortunately, such an assignment triggers a `SyntaxError`. A lamda does not accept a `raise` statement either. Is there a nicer variant than `exec()`?

```
lambda: exec("raise NotImplementedError()")
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a named function instead of a lambda:

```
def raise_not_implemented():
    raise NotImplementedError()
self._button_clicked = raise_not_implemented
```

Comment: Well, I had hoped not to define a method. But thanks for the answer anyway.